# KineticJS: How to make IE9 save canvas as image?

Tags: internet-explorer-9, kineticjs, todataurl

I'm using this snippet to save canvas as image : when I click the button **snapshot**, id="snap", a new tab in FF (or window, in chrome) is opened and the image is called.

```
document.getElementById('snap').addEventListener('click', function () {
    stage.toDataURL({
        callback: function call (dataUrl) {
            window.open(dataUrl);
        },
        mimeType: 'image/png',
        quality: 1
    })
});
```

The problem is that IE9 gives me an error and does not show the file. The error says that there is a software needed to open the file. Honestly, I don't understand this error, what software is Microsoft talking about? If there's any solution or workaround please help.

Comment: I've make this http://fiddle.jshell.net/n7ge3/ ... and then I realize that I don't have IE. Hope it can help other people to try it faster however... (working with chrome)

Comment: With IE, your code just opens an empty tab, no image :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that there is no solution to do it in full JS in IE curently...
A solution is available here, using a php query :

http://danielmclaren.com/node/90

```html
<?php
/**
 * an example URL for viewing a base64-encoded image:
 * http://example.com/decode.php?image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANS...
 */
$data = split(";", $_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"]);
$type = $data[0];
$data = split(",", $data[1]);
header("Content-type: ".$type);
echo base64_decode($data[1]);
?>
```

Comment: yeah, I saw a tutorial somewhere (more recent than that one) and it's the same concept: creating php page, etc... so I'll accept your answer. But for me, I'll leave the solution just like that because it's going to take some time. thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

*I have not tested this solution in IE*, but it works fine in Chrome 35.x.

Display the image on a jQueryUI dialog and prompt the user to perform right-click, save as.

Page code:

`<script srv='jquery-ui.js'></script>`

`<div id='ImageExportDialog'></div>`

Javascript:

`$('#ImageExportDialog').dialog({autoOpen:false, modal:true});`

Javascript:

`document.getElementById('ImageExportDialog').src = canvas.toDataURL();`